# Haskell "libraries"

Tags: haskell, compilation, shared-libraries

In C, one can split code into a "header file" and implementation, compile the implementation, and then just distribute the compiled version and the header only (not the full source).

Is this possible in Haskell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GHC allows for that, but of course your code will be tied to a specific binary platform.

Check here:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/2.10/users_guide/user_174.html

or for a more updated explanation:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html

In particular, look for .hi files.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to do this. When GHC compiles a Haskell module (i.e., a `*.hs` file), it generates executable code in a `*.o` object file, and also a `*.hi` "interface file". You only need the object file and interface file to use the compiled code.

However, unlike C, the run-time details of Haskell are not officially standardised. Consequently, you can't take code compiled with different Haskell compilers and link it together; the result won't work. In fact, often you can't even link together code compiled with different versions of GHC. It's not that there's anything "impossible" about doing this, it's just that nobody has standardised this stuff yet, so currently it doesn't work.

More recently, it is also possible to compile Haskell code into "dynamic libraries" (DLLs on Windows, `*.so` files on Unix). Again, you still need the `*.hi` files to compile against these, but at run-time you just need the library file itself.

Note that GHC tends to do *a lot* of cross-module optimisation, which somewhat reduces the usefulness of dynamic linking. (It's a bit like trying to "compile" a C++ template library...)

None of this matters of course if you're just interested in people not seeing your source code, or not having to supply a Haskell compiler to end-users.